# Calling a method from a class from an element within a list of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist, types

#### Background:

I have two classes `Book` and `Video`and a `Driver` class made to hold a list of `Book` and `Video` objects so to have a virtual library. Each class has a method `getTitle()` which returns the given title from first parameter of the class constructor as a `String`. Additionally, the `Driver` class has a method `getList()` which returns the list (`lib` in this context) as a `List<Object>`

#### Relevant Snippets:

```
List<Object> lib = new ArrayList<Object>();

// Params for each constructor is a single string for the title for this example
Book b = new Book("Book");
Video v = new Video("Video");
lib.add(b);
lib.add(v);
```

So, say I run something like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < lib.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println(getList().get(x).getClass());
}
```

The program will return

```
class Book
class Video
```

However, if I call a method from the `Book` or `Video` class (same method name):

```
for (int x = 0; x < lib.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println(getList().get(x).getTitle());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getTitle()
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

### So my question ultimately is,

How can I call `getTitle()` from an element within a list of Objects if the `getTitle()` method is not in the Object class? If I override `toString()` within the `Book` or `Video` class, it runs the `toString()` from `Book` or `Video`, as it should-- but it seems like the way it's running is flip-flopping between whether the elements of my list is an `Object` or an instance of one my classes.

#### Solutions I have thought about but don't know how to implement:

Casting elements back to `Book` or `Video`. *Challenge:* How to variably cast to multiple types & how to do it inline.

Using another array/list-like container which would allow for specific data types to keep `Book` and `Video`. *Challenge:* Unfamiliarity, possible over-complication, and I'd like to be able to use lists.

### Final Remarks

If you're wondering-- Yes, this is an assignment for class. That's why I need ONE list/array instead of two for each type, which would make my life much easier. The reason I didn't upload all of my code is for trying to make the question as simple as possible considering I have three unique classes I made, and there are much more than a `Title` and one method for each class. If it's pertinent, I could upload the actual code.

***Thank you for taking the time out of your day to think with me and work this out.***

Comment: Can you modify `Book` and `Video` classes or you cannot because of the assignment ?

Comment: I made the classes myself, yes I can change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a list of objects here; your library is intended to hold library-like things. A File isn't intended to be stored in here. Nor is a lock, an inputstream, an integer, a string, a car, a house, or a galaxy.

Define the concept of what can be stored in a library. Make this an interface:

```
public interface LibraryWork {
    String getTitle();
}
```

This says: There is such a thing as the notion of 'a library work', and all library works have in common that they have titles.

Then:

```
class Book implements LibraryWork {
    ...
}
```

Now, you can make your library have a list not of Object, which is quite useless and overly broad, but instad, a `List<LibraryWork>`.

And now you can call getTitle on it as much as you prefer.

Generally, avoid .getClass, instanceof, class casts, etc - if you must, make an enum of library work kinds and have your Book class return 'BOOK' if you must.

NB: I'm not too fond of the name LibraryWork, perhaps you can think of something better.

Comment: If the only thing on the interface is `String getTitle()`, then I've adopted the convention from some Google projects of `HasTitle`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- that breaks most sensible naming conventions I've ever read. 'HasTitle' does not really describe much. In this case, it goes a lot deeper than just 'anything that has a title' (can I store a living human in a library? I don't think so). 'Work' does cover the concept, except 'work' is unfortunately in english rather burdened with a lot of unfortunate homonyms.

Comment: > the only thing on the interface

Comment: That's not relevant. You're putting the cart before the horse. If we stick with your logic, then there should only ever be one marker interface, and it should be called 'MarkerInterface'. We actually have a ton of them. First you consider what the thing is, then you describe the methods it has (which might be a disappointingly small list). What you're describing is a way of making java act like a crappy structurally typed language.

Comment: This is a perfect solution to my problem. Unfortunately my professor will only take arrays/lists, and the toString() override that actually works is all he wanted. However, for my own enjoyment and learning I decided to make a duplicate which implemented this solution. Thank you very much my friend.